# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and multilabel-indicator targets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

**Hello I'm getting this error for my prediction model. I'm getting datas from an excel file with 4 input and 4 output. I'm new in deep learning. I can see it's about y_test but I dont know what I should write exactly. Here's my code. Thanks for any help in advance**

```
df = pd.read_excel ("C:/Users/hayri/Desktop/aa.xlsx") 

xdata = df

print(xdata)


min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(xdata)

df = pd.read_excel ("C:/Users/hayri/Desktop/bb.xlsx") 

ydata = df


min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(ydata)


(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)= train_test_split(x_scaled,y_scaled,test_size = 0.2,random_state=0)



conv = Sequential()
conv.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu', input_shape=(4, 4)))

conv.add(Dropout(0.5))
conv.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
conv.add(Flatten())
conv.add(Dense(4, activation = 'sigmoid'))


sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.3, momentum = 0.6, decay = 0, nesterov = False)
conv.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer ='sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'])
history=conv.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size =10, epochs =200,validation_data=(x_test,y_test), verbose = 1)
score = conv.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=10)

y_test=np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)

y_pred = conv.predict(x_test,batch_size=64)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

results = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred) 
sns.heatmap(results,cmap="Blues")

accuracy = conv.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer ='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size =10, epochs =200,validation_data=(x_test,y_test), verbose = 1)
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=10)

    y_pred = model.predict(x_test,batch_size=64)
    y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
```

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing more of your code. if you want to post the entire thing, along with your input shape and data type, i'm willing to help.

Comment: Hi I edited and add whole code, now I'm getting this error; ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 4 from 1 for 'conv1d_15/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,64], [1,4,64,32].